# AUC from averaged class probabilities in caret R

Tags: r, r-caret, auc

I'd like to obtain the area under the curve (AUC) from my binary classifier after cross-validation using the `caret` package.

For the standard confusion matrix, I use the `average` argument in the `caret::confusionMatrix`.

Example:

```
controls = trainControl(method="repeatedcv"
                    , number=5
                    , repeats=10
                    , selectionFunction = "oneSE"
                    , classProbs = T
                    , summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
)

svm_5k = train(veracity ~ .
           , data = training_data
           , method = "svmLinear"
           , trControl = controls
           , verbose = FALSE
           , metric = 'ROC'
)
```

And then the confusion matrix is used for accuracy, F1, etc.

```
confmat = caret::confusionMatrix(svm_5k
                             , 'average')
```

Now I struggle with the AUC: I am now retrieving the class probs and attach them as column to the testing data like `testing_data$prob = predict(svm_5k, testing_data, type='prob')[,2]`

If I then use the `pROC` package to obtain the AUC like

`roc(response = testing_data$veracity, predictor = testing_data$prob)` ...

... I am not using the cross-validation as indicated in the `controls` but merely the snapshot of the classifier.

Is there any way to use the averaged probabilities from the CV to get the AUC?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
predict = predict(svm_5k, testing_data)
roc <- roc(testing_data$veracity, as.numeric(predict))
```

now u can get all the stuff u need from roc like sensitivities, specificities and area under curve.

```
auc <- auc(roc)
sens <- roc$sensitivities[2]
spec <- roc$specificities[2]
```

Comment: But this would not give the average of the different CVs. As you describe it, it's similar to what I did. Yet, I want to avoid to get predictions from only one iteration but rather the average of all CV repeats.

Comment: Idk i had a similar task but i used 10 fold cross validation, made a field of auc. In for loops i concatenated them and at the end i used mean.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue, what you want is stored inside your model under `svm_5k$pred`.

To plot the AUC, you can do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotROC)
ggplot(svm_5k$pred, 
       aes(m = M, d = factor(obs, levels = c("R", "M")))) + 
    geom_roc(hjust = -0.4, vjust = 1.5) + coord_equal()
```

where `M` is a value depends on your model under `svm_5k$pred`. and "R" and "M" are just the labels.

So in my case, `m = Yes` and `levels = c("Yes", "No")`. Something like that